# Vue.js <template> inside <tr> with IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, vue.js

I have a template where inside each `tr`, I need to show two `td`s. This is accomplished with a hierarchy like this:

```
tbody
  tr v-for
    template v-for
      td
      td
```

Yes, there's a loop within a loop. Chrome has no trouble with this, but IE refuses to display it. Do I have any options here?

Comment: template isn't supported in IE at all http://caniuse.com/#feat=template . There isn't a way to do this that I know of, you'll have to manually spell out the tds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff already explained the problem in his comment (IE's lack of support for `<template>`).

A sort of hacky way to deal with this is to use a component and the `is=""` property:

```
<tr v-for="thing in things">
  <td v-for="subThing in thing" is="hackyComponent" :item="subThing">
```

and in hackyComponent:

```
<td>{{item.a}}</td>
<td>{{item.b}}</td>

export default {
 replace: true //replaces the original <td> with the template content
               // Vue might complain about creating a "Fragment Instance" in development, but that's not a real problem.

}
```